# Lombok doesn't generate getters in hybris custom component

Tags: java, spring, sap-commerce-cloud, lombok, annotation-processing

I have a custom hybris component. I added the following to the `external-dependencies.xml`

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.12</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

The Lombok plugin is installed, the annotation processing is enabled. In the IDE I see the generated methods, but when I run `ant clean all` I get errors.

For example here is a test class:

```
@Data
public class TestDto {

    private String prop;
}
```

Here is an example usage of it

```
        TestDto test = new TestDto();
        test.setProp("");
        test.getProp();
```

But the `ant clean all` says the following:

```
   [yjavac] Compiling 700 source files to /Users/myUser/Projects/MyProject/hybris/myComponent/classes
   [yjavac] ----------
   [yjavac] 1. ERROR in /Users/myUser/Projects/MyProject/hybris/myComponent/src/service/ExampleService.java (at line 65)
   [yjavac]     test.setProp("");
   [yjavac]          ^^^^^^^
   [yjavac] The method setProp(String) is undefined for the type TestDto
   [yjavac] ----------
   [yjavac] 2. ERROR in /Users/myUser/Projects/MyProject/hybris/myComponent/src/service/ExampleService.java (at line 66)
   [yjavac]     test.getProp();
   [yjavac]          ^^^^^^^
   [yjavac] The method getProp() is undefined for the type TestDto
   [yjavac] ----------
   [yjavac] 2 problems (2 errors)

BUILD FAILED
```

What am I missing?

Edit:

Here is the `extensioninfo.xml`. Maven is enabled.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<extensioninfo xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="extensioninfo.xsd">

    <extension abstractclassprefix="Generated" classprefix="MyPrefix" managername="MyManager"
               managersuperclass="de.hybris.platform.jalo.extension.Extension" name="myName" usemaven="true">
        <requires-extension name="Mycore"/>
        <requires-extension name="Mymqintegration"/>
        <requires-extension name="Mycommons"/>

        <coremodule generated="true" manager="com.example.api.jalo.MyManager"
                    packageroot="com.example.api"/>

        <webmodule jspcompile="false" webroot="/api"/>
    </extension>

</extensioninfo>
```

Edit2:

I found some tips about `buildcallbacks.xml`. I'm pretty new in hybris so I went trough some google -> copy -> paste -> try -> repeat cycle with the buildcallbacks but none of the found solution worked for me.

Here are some example I tried out without any success:

```
<target name="myModuleName_lombok">
    <javac srcdir="src" destdir="build" source="1.8">
           <classpath location="lib/lombok-1.18.12.jar"/>
    </javac>
    <echo message="     adding lombok"/>
</target>
```

```
<macrodef name="myExtName_before_build">
            <sequential>
                <addToClasspath classpathproperty="ext.MyExtName.classpath" path="${ext.MyExtname.path}/lib/lombok-1.18.12.jar"/>
            </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

Comment: Have you double checked [lombok ant build doc](https://projectlombok.org/setup/ant)? The key points are: 1) Have JDK >= 1.6. 2) have lombok.jar in your javac class path.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that but I cannot edit the build.xml because it is generated by hybris every time. I found that if I wanna modify the build process I should edit the buildcallbacks.xml but I can't figure it out how to pass the classpath correctly in the buildcallbacks.xml

Comment: Have you edited the extensioninfo.xml(from your extension directory) in order to allow maven use(i.e usemaven="true") ?

Comment: Yeah. Maven is enabled and there are a few other dependencies that work without any problem.

Comment: I have the same problem. All mentioned attempts try to get Lombok into the classpath. I'm quite sure, that this part works, because `new lombok.Lombok();` or `@lombok.Getter private final String prop;` compiles just fine. The problem appears to be the byte code generation, because calling `getProp()` does not compile, like in the example above. (This is my current state of investigation and I don't know how to solve this.)

Comment: Hey @Huntszy, did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Comment: Hey @Cyrois. No, couldn't find any working solution. In the end we just decided to not use Lombok in the project.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment about Lombok, because I haven't used it in Hybris. But, the usual (and probably the proper way) to create Data or DTO classes is via the *-beans.xml.

You would normally have something like this instead:

```
<bean class="com.demo.facades.dto.TestDto">
    <property name="prop" type="String" />
</bean>
```

Reference:

- Generating Beans and Enums: https://help.sap.com/viewer/d0224eca81e249cb821f2cdf45a82ace/1905/en-US/8bc53579866910149472ccbef0222ec5.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the way that the ant builds:

https://projectlombok.org/setup/ant

To implement this customization in ant create a file called buildcallbacks.xml in its extension:

https://wiki.hybris.com/x/YIVvAg

Comment: Yeah, I heard about it but I couldn't solve my problem with it. I updated the question with the details of my buildcallbacks modifications.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with Hybris and Lombock is due to the compiler configuration from the properties file.

```
build.compiler=org.eclipse.jdt.core.JDTCompilerAdapter
```

if you change the property to

```
build.compiler=modern
```

the compilation process will pass fine. However, I can't guarantee that there will be no side effects.